# Load database into Postgresql in Dbeaver

Tags: postgresql, import, dbeaver

I have a sample database from [this tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/). I want to work with this database in Dbeaver. When I provide a path to the database in Dbeaver I get an error. [image]

What is the procedure to work with the database in Dbeaver?

Comment: You need to **extract** the content of the tar file and then **import** the database into your Postgres server - exactly what the tutorial describes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install pgAdmin and follow the tutorial you linked. Following, expand the Databases tab in the left. There you will see all the available databases. There should be the one you have imported - probably named "dvdrental" or so. Then just type in the database name in the Database field in dbeaver

Comment: I did it through pgadmin and it worked. But the question is more general, given a local database how to connect it to dbeaver?

Comment: Login to your pgAdmin, and expand the Databases tab in the left. There you will see all the available databases. There should be the one you have imported - probably named "dvdrental "or so. Then just type in the database name in the Database field in dbeaver.

Comment: Wow... that's simple. Please, update the answer with the comment and I will accept it.

Comment: Dude question is about dbeaver and you are telling how to do it in pgadmin.